Vite React App Deploys Successfully on Render but Returns HTTP ERROR 502
Issue:
I have created a Vite React app that works perfectly on my local machine. However, when I deployed the Vite project on Render, I encountered an issue. Here are the details:
Deployment Process:
The deployment process completes without any errors.
The logs show that the build is successful and the service is live.
Deployment Logs:
Deploying...
==> Build uploaded in 8s
==> Build successful 
==> Using Node version 20.12.2 (default)
==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
==> Using Bun version 1.1.0 (default)
==> Docs on specifying a bun version: https://render.com/docs/bun-version
==> Running 'npm run dev'

Issue:

Despite the logs indicating that the service is live, when I try to open the link, I receive the following error message:

This page isn’t working
assessmentwebsite-user1.onrender.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 502



The Render logs provide the following error details:

Error: The service was stopped
    at /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/vite/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1111:28
    at responseCallbacks.<computed> (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/vite/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:704:9)
    at Socket.afterClose (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/vite/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:694:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:530:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)


**Steps Taken:
**

I verified that the app runs correctly on my local machine using npm run dev.
I ensured that all environment variables are correctly set on Render.

Request for Help:
I would appreciate any guidance on resolving this issue. Specifically, I'm looking for:

Possible reasons for the HTTP ERROR 502 on Render.
Steps to troubleshoot and fix the issue related to the Vite build or deployment process.

Thank you for your assistance!
